# Bug on the modal bootstrap after execute window.print on popup window

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

i'm using modal bootstrap and it doesn't open that after execute the `window.print` on popup window. When i cancel printing the modal bootstrap is showed.

It´s only happen in the Chrome.

This is the code where we can simulate clicking on the button `"OpenPopup"` and after the button `"OpenModal"`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://luissantana.com.br/pdv/themes/default/assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://luissantana.com.br/pdv/themes/default/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://luissantana.com.br/pdv/themes/default/assets/styles/theme.css" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function Popup(data) {
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'sma_pos_print', 'height=500,width=300');
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print</title>');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
            mywindow.document.write(data);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();
            return true;
        }

        function onClickOpenPopup() {
            Popup('teste');
        }

        function onClickOpenModal() {
            $('#susModal').modal();
        }       
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="onClickOpenPopup();" value="OpenPopup" class="botao"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="onClickOpenModal();" value="OpenModal" />
        <div class="modal fade in" id="susModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="susModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i
                                class="fa fa-2x">&times;</i></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="susModalLabel">TESTE</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Teste</p>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            asdasdasd
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" id="suspend_sale" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you have a Js Fiddle for this,if yes then please share the link.